# Expression Blend - Copy Object and Keyframes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend, expression-blend-4, expression-blend-5

Is there a way to copy-paste an control and keep all of its keyframes?

Everything I've tried will copy the control and have a completely blank animation for the copied control. This seems like it would be easily done by manually editing Xaml, but is there a way to do it from the Blend UI?

I'm using the new [VS 2012 Blend Preview+Sketchflow](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702), but I've tried in VS 2012 Blend and Blend 4 also with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're copying the Control, you're just copying the object, if you want the animations ('StoryBoard') you'll have to grab those separately from the `Resources` which don't appear in the Objects and Timeline Panel so they can't be selected like a standard object.

What you could do though, is if you're trying to re-use the same `StoryBoard` in multiple places, place the `StoryBoard` in a Resource Dictionary available globally then you don't have to worry about copying it to each instance. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it's not an entire storyboard, but just a single animation within the storyboard. Is there a way to copy a control and make copies of any animations with `Storyboard.TargetName` set to that control as well?

Comment: Hmm, you would think so but not that I'm aware of without copying that storyboard and making it unique to the new target instance. Unless maybe you could expose it as a dependency property and bind the value in the storyboard perhaps? Sorry, I know that's not exactly the answer you were probably hoping for, guess I misunderstood the question a bit.

Comment: Thanks though. I'm thinking I could potentially write a C# extension to Blend to do what I want, I think it may be the only option.